# Magebto 2: Order place for customer using oauth authentication instead token

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

How to access magento 2 api for customer, guest and admin using oauth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 it is  depricated for customer and admin token using oauth